# 周期境界条件がおもいつかない

Tags: python, julia

pythonからJuliaに移行しました。
ここで、Juliaの配列において、0がないことの問題にあたっています。
以下のpythonのコードの周期境界条件をJuliaに書き換えようとしていいるのですが、式が浮かびません、、、。

```
x1 = (x-1 + n) %n
x2 = (x+1) % n
y1 = (y-1 + n) %n
y2 = (y+1) % n
z1 = (z-1 + n) %n
z2 = (z+1) % n
```

x=0のとき、ひだりからnが作用する（ｙ、ｚ）も同様。
ただ今回はｘが１なのでどのように上の条件式を書き換えれば。。。
ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Comment: 配列のインデックス(添字)が 1-base という事であれば `x1 = ((x-1 + (n-1)) % n) + 1`, `x2 = ((x+1 + (n-1)) % n) + 1` でしょうか(y, z も同様)。分かりやすくするために冗長な表記をしています(Julia であればコンパイル時に定数部分を計算してくれると思います)。

Comment: ありがとうございます・・・！！！